# How to perform this GqlQuery?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have the datastore as follows,

```
class Data(db.Model):
     project = db.StringProperty()
     project_languages = db.ListProperty(str,default=[])
```

When user inputs a language (`input_language`), I want to output all the projects which contains the language user mentioned in it's language list (`project_languages`).

I tried to do it in the below way but got an error saying,

`BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Condition`

`db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE input_language IN project_languages")`

What should be my query, if I want to get the data in the above mentioned way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using python for the job.. If so I highly recommend you use the  **ndb** library for datastore queries. The solution is easy as `Data.query(A.IN(B))`